# async function and await keyword not returning any value

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I am trying to get the `SourceID` of the document in Async call using await keyword but I am not getting the value.

I am new to this concept, could anyone tell where I am doing mistake.

I have added my code in below code snippet:

```
public async GetListItems(ListTitle: string): Promise<any[]> {
   debugger;
   let ListCardItemsArray: ListCardListItem[] = [];
   let ListCardListItm: ListCardListItem = null;

   return new Promise<any[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
       await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(ListTitle).items.select("*").get().then((results: any) => {
           results.map((result: any) => {
               let sourceID: string;
               ListCardListItm = new ListCardListItem();
               ListCardListItm["Title"] = result.Title;
               ListCardListItm["Description"] = result.Description;
               ListCardListItm["DocumentURL"] = result.DocumentURL;
              //here i am calling my method
               let sourceID =  this.GetSourceID("");
               ListCardListItm["SourceID"] = "";
               ListCardListItm["VisioURL"] = result.VisioURL;
               ListCardItemsArray.push(ListCardListItm);
           })
           console.log(ListCardItemsArray);
           resolve(ListCardItemsArray);
       }, (error: any) => {
           console.log("Error of GetListItems " + error);
           resolve(error);
       });
     });
}


public async GetSourceID(LinkURL: string) {
   let sourceID: string = "";
   try {
       let result = await sp.web.getFileByUrl("https://contosa.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/sites/Sample/SampleLibrary/Sample.vsdx?d=we836259ffe4b4f6c96ca6dd1118e6629&csf=1&web=1&e=B2w69d").select("*").get();
       sourceID = await result.UniqueId;
       console.log(sourceID);
       return sourceID;
   } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below code and it's working fine

```
public async GetSampleListItems(ListTitle: string): Promise<any[]> {
    debugger;
    let ListCardItemsArray: ListCardListItem[] = [];
    let ListCardListItm: ListCardListItem = null;
    let resultsArray: any = [];

    return await new Promise<any[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
     try {
            resultsArray = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(ListTitle).items.select("*").get();
            for (let index = 0; index < resultsArray.length; index++) {
                ListCardListItm = new ListCardListItem();
                const element = resultsArray[index];
                ListCardListItm["Title"] = element.Title;
                ListCardListItm["Description"] = element.Description;
                ListCardListItm["DocumentURL"] = element.DocumentURL;
                
                let sourceID = await this.GetSourceID(element.VisioURL ? 
                      element.VisioURL["Url"] : "");

                //sourceID = ;
                ListCardListItm["SourceID"] = sourceID;
                ListCardListItm["VisioURL"] = element.VisioURL;
                ListCardItemsArray.push(ListCardListItm);
            }
            //})
            console.log(ListCardItemsArray);
            resolve(ListCardItemsArray);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("GetSampleListItems= " + error);
        }
    });
}

public async GetSourceID(LinkURL: string) {
        let sourceID: string = "";
        try {
            let result = await sp.web.getFileByUrl(LinkURL).select("*").get();
            sourceID = await result.UniqueId;
            console.log(sourceID);
            return sourceID;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change `GetListItems()` function to:

```
//here i am calling my method
let sourceID = await this.GetSourceID("https://contosa.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/sites/Sample/SampleLibrary/Sample.vsdx?d=we836259ffe4b4f6c96ca6dd1118e6629&csf=1&web=1&e=B2w69d");
ListCardListItm["SourceID"] = sourceID;
```

& use:

```
public async GetSourceID(LinkURL: string): Promise<string> {
    let sourceID: string = "";
    try {
      let result = await sp.web.getFileByUrl(LinkURL).select("*").get();
      sourceID = result.UniqueId;
      console.log(sourceID);
      return sourceID;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return sourceID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh.

I am getting this below error when i place this below code in GetListItems() Method

let sourceID = await this.GetSourceID("https://contosa.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/sites/Sample/SampleLibrary/Sample.vsdx?d=we836259ffe4b4f6c96ca6dd1118e6629&csf=1&web=1&e=B2w69d");

'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: Your GetListItems() Method is already `async`, right?